# Help with design problem (extending a generic inteface)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, observer-pattern

I am part of a studentproject and we are to develop a product for a company using Java EE. As "lead architect" in the project I am responsible for composing a good design which should be flexible for further extensions.

Background info: We are to develop a website with a drag and drop GUI with possibilites to connect data sources with data manipulations to perform on that specific data. The GUI should be generic and possible to integrate with upcoming products. This means that we cannot code to an implementation in the presentation layer. Instead we will use an interface to define what kind of data manipulations that are possible for all kinds of products. However, each product might also sport product specific data manipulations (thus extending the interface with more methods).

The problem I have with the scenario above is that I dont see how we could pass on these "product specific data manipulations" to the GUI and say that, in addition to the generic interface, we also possess these data manipulation actions...

Now I had a discussion with some of the more experienced programmers from the company and they told me that there is a common solution to this problem - more specifically known as the "Observer pattern". They draw something like `[1]` on the whiteboard and explained that it would be possible to "register" to a third party (getApplicationContext) that in turn could convey our product specific interface. This is a common problem to get rid of those nasty circular dependencies, they explained.

I have now had a look on the observer pattern and how it works and I still dont really get how I am supposed to solve the design problem. Could someone possibly try to explain how it would turn out in my specific scenario? I have no real problem understanding how it works with "subjects" and "observers".

Here is an UML diagram of the design where we are using a reference of the specific product. This is what is undesirable and something we would like to get around.

(maybe I got this all wrong...)

I am sorry but I cant change the picture to the correct one as I am a new user... Here is a link to an updated UML diagram:

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/2mbfno.png]

Comment: Was the question too unclear? I think this should be a re-occuring problem in software design... I am just trying to do a good job and learn those things that I didnt understand, so that I can perform as good as possible the coming week.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for is the [Model View Controller](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller-model) design pattern. The [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is just a part of this design pattern. There is a short description for doing this with Java Servlets and JavaServer Pages from Java EE on the [wikipedia article](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller-model).